# Cassandra Data Modeling : Dynamic column

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling

I have a table user_activity.

```
user_activity
{
user_id text
user_name text
email_id text
password text
activity1 text}
```

Is it possible to add column dynamically?

```
for ex -

user1(user_id : Rowkey)

user_name, emai_id, password, activity1, activity2 

user2(user_id : Rowkey)

user_name, emai_id, password, activity1, activity2, activity3

user3(user_id : Rowkey)

user_name, emai_id, password, activity1
```

since activities could be of any number.

thanks in advance :)

Comment: This is not possible using CQL... earlier thrift used to support it.... but you can have column of datatype map

Answer (score 1):

**You can use [Map](http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.0/cql/cql_using/use_map_t.html)**

For example :

```
CREATE TABLE user_activity (
    user_id text primary key,
    emai_id text,
    password text,
    activity map<text,text>
);
```

Insert :

```
INSERT INTO user_activity (user_id, emai_id, password, activity) VALUES ('1', 'a1@b.com','password1', {'activity1'  : 'test activity 1', 'activity2' : 'test acitivty 2' });
```

Update :

```
UPDATE user_activity SET activity['activity1'] = 'updated test activity 1' where user_id = '1';
```

Delete :

```
DELETE activity['activity2'] FROM user_activity WHERE user_id = '1';
```

*Note : Keep the collection (map) size small, In Cassandra for map Maximum number of keys: 65535 and values size: 65535*